# SharePoint 2013 Requirements

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have windows server 2012 and Sql 2014 edition. Can I use that for SharePoint 2013 Farm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll need at least the May 2014 Cumulative Update applied to SharePoint prior to using SQL 2014.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2014 requires the May 2014 Cumulative Update to be installed. To install the May 2014 Cumulative Update see [Updates to SharePoint 2013.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/jj891062)

more read here: [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#section4)